# Почему axios отправляет пустой объект вместо map?

Tags: javascript, json, axios

Я использую `React` и `axios`. Пытаюсь отправлять запрос:

```
/* Здесь создаётся объект axios */
const apiRequester = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    withCredentials: true
});

/* Данный метод должен отправить запрос */
const saveOpenParagraphs = (id, paragraphsToSave) => {
    console.log(paragraphsToSave)
    return apiRequester.post('programs/' + id + '/open-paragraphs', paragraphsToSave, {
        headers: {
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': getXSRFToken()
        }
    });
}

/* Не имеет прямого отношения к вопросу, но мало ли, вдруг как-то влияет */
const getXSRFToken = () => {
    return Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
}
```

Объект `paragraphsToSave` это карта, мапа. Вот как она выглядит в консоли *(логируется непосредственно перед отправкой запроса)*:

```
Map(22) {100007 => 400, 100015 => 900, 100016 => 1000, 100017 => 1100, 100018 => 1200, …}
[[Entries]]
0: {100007 => 400}
1: {100015 => 900}
2: {100016 => 1000}
3: {100017 => 1100}
4: {100018 => 1200}
5: {100019 => 1300}
6: {100020 => 1400}
7: {100021 => 1500}
8: {100022 => 1600}
9: {100023 => 1700}
10: {100024 => 1800}
11: {100027 => 2100}
12: {100028 => 2200}
13: {100029 => 2300}
14: {100030 => 2400}
15: {100031 => 2500}
16: {100032 => 2600}
17: {100033 => 2700}
18: {100035 => 2800}
19: {100036 => 3000}
20: {100037 => 3100}
21: {100038 => 3200}
size: (...)
__proto__: Map
```

Во кладке `network` тело запроса выглядит так:

```
{}
```

Почему такое происходит? Остальные объекты отправляются нормально *(раньше карту не отправлял)*, а здесь тело запроса пустое. Как исправить?

Comment: оберните map в ```JSON.stringify()```

Comment: И обнаружить что как раз и получается `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Почему axios отправляет пустой объект вместо map?*

А с чего бы axios'у поступать иначе? (риторический вопрос)
Если посмотреть [в документацию этой библиотеки](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) - то можно заметить, что там вполне однозначно перечислены допустимые типы значений:

> `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
> Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH'
> When no `transformRequest` is set, **must be of one of the following types:**
>
> - **string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, URLSearchParams**
> - Browser only: **FormData, File, Blob**
> - Node only: **Stream, Buffer**

То есть, о поддержке `Map` не заявлено.
Зато упомянута возможность использования свойства конфигурации `transformRequest`, которое служит для модификации данных запроса передаваемых в методы axios. Описание данного свойства находится выше по тексту той же самой страницы документации. Если вкратце: оно принимает массив коллбэков, которые будут вызываться (с двумя аргументами - тело запроса, объект заголовков) перед отправкой запроса, и последний из коллбэков должен вернуть окончательное значение тела запроса в одном из поддерживаемых библиотекой типов (`string | Buffer | ArrayBuffer | FormData | Stream`).

---

> *Как исправить?*

Обычным для опенсорсного продукта путем: форкнуть [репозиторий проекта](https://github.com/axios/axios) ➝ реализовать в библиотеке поддержку значений типа `Map` ➝ убедиться в соблюдении всех рекомендаций/требований [руководства для соавторов](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/COLLABORATOR_GUIDE.md) ➝ отправить авторам PR.

Comment: Ну про опенсорс это вы конечно загнули) если бы я настолько знал js, я бы такие вопросы не задавал)

Answer (score 1):

Из ответа [@yar85](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/288409/yar85) стало понятно, что надо каким-то образом привести объект `Map` к `string`, потому что карту в чистом виде axios не воспринимает.

Моё решение оказалось очень простым, хотя оно, вероятно, не является оптимальным. Но у меня простая карта, где в качестве ключа и значения выступают примитивы, поэтому мне такое решение подошло:

```
JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(paragraphsToSave))
```

Первая функция `Object.fromEntries` вернула карту в виде простого объекта:

```
{100007: 400, 100015: 900, ...}
```

А `JSON.stringify` вернул из объекта строку.

Вы можете подробнее прочитать про различные способы преобразования объекта `Map` в строку в следующих источниках: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085197/how-do-you-json-stringify-an-es6-map), [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57252151/convert-mapstring-object-to-json-in-javascript), [ссылка](https://2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html).

Comment: _«надо каким-то образом привести объект Map к string»_ - на самом деле, не обязательно именно к `string`, и не обязательно именно в коллбэке `transformRequest` (я упомянул лишь одно из решений, самое очевидное). Другим решением может быть типкаст экземпляра `Map` вообще до передачи аргументом в `axios.post`. То есть, какого-то универсального js-выражения "на все случаи жизни" здесь дать нельзя, т.к. случаи эти разные => решения в них разные. Влияют и версия ES, и кодирование тела запроса, и сами данные. А для отправки джейсона, вариант в твоем ответе очень хороший (+).

Comment: @yar85 да, собственно, с тем и столкнулся, что способов преобразовать map в json сходу нашлось около десятка, в зависимости от ситуации)